# call function at end of timer rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi I want to call the function at the end of timer finished in rxjs.

```
this.timer$ = timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
  scan(acc => acc = acc - 1000, milliseconds),
  takeWhile(x => x >= 0),
  tap(() => {
    console.log('function finished')
  })
)
```

The above code working but how can I define a function what should call after the timer expired.

I tried with `tap` method but it is **not working**

Comment: Where did you see `tap` as deprecated?

Comment: https://nimb.ws/YVsb2Q showing something but when wrote whole statment then it gone.
My mistake. I improved the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `finalize`, `takeWile` will complete the observable when condition match and trigger `finalize`

```
this.timer$ = timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
  scan(acc => acc = acc - 1000, milliseconds),
  takeWhile(x => x >= 0),
  finalize(() => {
    console.log('function finished')
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timer(1000,2000).pipe(take(4)).subscribe(console.log)
```

Did you say `take`

Comment: what is 4 here ?, I want to call a function when the timer gets 0 or in negative